# Azure Data Lake Store Access Thru Proxy Using Java SDK

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-java-sdk

I could not see a way to set proxy in Azure Data Lake Store Client SDK. I am working in a corporate network and I have to set proxy while using Azure and ResourceManager classes (.withProxy(..)) to be able to access Azure. Am I missing something or isn't that really available?
Thanks

Edit:
I saw that setting proxy properties did not help. However, I found out that when while creating DataLakeStoreAccountManagementClientImpl, I could use the constructor accepting RestClient. While creating RestClient using "usingProxyAuthenticator" and/or "usingProxy" methods according to needs and passing to client constructor, solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK itself can't have any proxy settings. You might need to check settings of the IDE (Visual Studio for example) you are using. Another easier way would be to use tools such as Proxifier.

Comment: I heard that it could be solved by setting proxy with system.props. However don't forget code will also run on server which will hit proxy. So IDE settings will save you while developing your code.